# jQuery calendar showing only days

Tags: jquery, html, calendar

I am in search for a calendar that shows only days after selecting year on **select box** and month on another **select box**.The **result** that comes is, total days of that month, after selection of year and month in two individual select box.And after that I can make selection from that result i.e total days of that month . But in a calendar it **doesn't show any weeks**,it shows only days.Can I have examples in jQuery which fulfils this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not a optimized code but just for your reference. Hope that this will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var y, m, d;
  var date = new Date();
  var i;
  for (i = -5; i < 5; i ++) {
    $("#cal").append("<li class='yearPicker'>" + (date.getFullYear() + i) + "</li>");
  }
  
  $(".yearPicker").click(function(){
    y = $(this).html();
    $("#cal").html("");
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i ++) {
      $("#cal").append("<li class='monthPicker'>" + (i + 1) + "</li>");
    }
    
    $(".monthPicker").click(function(){
      m = $(this).html();
      $("#cal").html("");
      date = new Date(y, m - 1, 1)
      for (i = 0; i < 31; i ++) {
        if (date.getMonth() == m - 1) {
          $("#cal").append("<li class='dayPicker'>" + (i + 1) + "</li>");
        } else {
          break;
        }
        
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      }
      
      $(".dayPicker").click(function(){
        alert(y + "/" + m + "/" + $(this).html());
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
ol {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="cal">
</ol>
```

Comment: This helps me a lot..thanks for that but i want month in a combo box and month in a another combo box.. and days in straight line.. And sorry , Because I hadn't provided the requirement properly..please help me out..

Comment: "i want month in a combo box and month in a another combo box..."??? Are you mean years and months in two different combo box? Then you can change the example instead of keep reuse the #cal, point to your `select` tag instead. Once the year combo box on change, populate the months combo box and so on.

Comment: yes that means two combo box.I did but i didn't get result.Could you help me in code..How can populate the months combo box..

Comment: What you had tried so far? Please let me see your code so that I can advice. Btw, I believe you can hardcode months as number of months always same. The more "challenging" part is on day but I think my example already provide enough information on how to do it.

Comment: ok i will try...thanks for your help..it really helps me a lot..

Comment: I made some changes as you told me to do..I changed the id #cal with select tag and li with option tag..but i found year  on both the select box.I have used  change method but couldn't get the result.can you help me in finding the solution..

Comment: can you put your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ so that I can help you debug it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bch0uqh0/1/   .please check it..

Comment: from code that you provided, seems like you are very new in programming. When you using jquery, if you put `$("select")`, it will change all your dropdown list. Try to use id instead like `$("#someid")`. Secondly, since you are using dropdown, use `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).html()`. Third, try to construct dropdown using syntax `<option value="someValue">display value</option>`. Changed code in [Update](http://jsfiddle.net/bch0uqh0/2). Be sure you understand it.

Comment: ..yes I am very new in programming.. thanks for your guidance and advice..